# Was a shaved female orangutan used as a prostitute at an Indonesian brothel?

Tags: prostitution

According to [*The New York Times* (2017-11-04)](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/11/04/world/africa/ape-trafficking-bonobos-orangutans.html) ([no paywall page](http://archive.is/6bcJl)):

> Several years ago, the Indonesian police rescued a female orangutan who had been shaved and was being used as a prostitute at a brothel.

No further detail is furnished. No source is given for the above information, though as the article is written, I infer that this information was from one "Daniel Stiles, a self-styled ape detective who lives in Kenya".

So is this claim true or false? Did any human being ever pay for sex with an orangutan in Indonesia?

Comment: I am ashamed that I could not resist clicking on this. The poor animal.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**This claim is true, according to a NGO dedicated to the conservation of Bornean Orangutans.**

The Orangutan, named Pony, was shaved every day and used as a prostitute in a village located in Indonesian Borneo.
Policemen rescued her in 2003 and she was put under the care of the Borneo Orangutan Survival Foundation (BOSF).

The BOSF confirms it on their [website](http://orangutan.or.id/update-on-pony/) and Michelle Desilets, BOSF director, talks about it in a [Vice interview](https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/dpdnp7/yo1-v14n10) and on her [Twitter](https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3Aorangutans%20Pony&src=typd).

Comment: When I saw this question, I asked myself "how the hell are you supposed to verify that?" And then when I read the link in your answer... OMFG. Cannot unsee!